# Continuity of a piecewise function with left and right hand limits

Tags: real-analysis

Q: For which values $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$ is the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} x^3+1 & x\leq 2 \\ \alpha x+\beta & 2 < x < 4 \\ x^2 & x\geq 4\end{cases}
\end{equation} continuous? Give reasons or your answer in terms of left and right hand limits of $f$ at $x=2$ and $x=4$.

I have had a go at this question and here it is. [image]

But I feel as if i haven't said if $f$ is continuous at points other than $x=2$ and $x=4$. the question talks about $f$ being continuous and not $f$ being continuous at only $x=2$ and $x=4$. How do I do this question in a full formal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let y be a real number.

if $y<2$, there is a $\delta >0$ s.e $(y-\delta,y+\delta)$ is all inside $(-\infty,2)$.
Therefore, in this open set f is defined as $f(x)=x^3+1$, so it's continious at $y$ as a polynomial (more detailed: let ${x_n}$ be a sequence that converges to $y$, so starting at some point $x_n$ is all in $(y-\delta,y+\delta)$, so $\text {lim}(f(x_n))=\text {lim}(x_n^3+1)=f( \text {lim }x_n)=f(y)$, so f is continous at y).

you do the same for any "middle point". for the edges, you do as you mentioned.

Comment: My lecturer said that we have to mention the algebra of continuous functions, how is this done?